# Accessing JSON array after it has been streamed, Flash as3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I have the following code:

```
import flash.utils.describeType;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
import flash.text.TextField;

stop();

var chartsURL : URLRequest = new URLRequest();
chartsURL.url="http://zagony.net/charts.php"
chartsURL.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;

var streamer:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
streamer.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receive);
streamer.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, missing);
streamer.load(chartsURL);

function receive (event : Event) : void
{
    var buttonsCount:int = 0;

    var json : String = event.target.data;
    var myResults:Object = JSON.parse(json);
    //trace(json);
    for each(var data:Object in myResults)
    {
        var listItem:ListItem = new ListItem();
        addChild(listItem);

        listItem.y = 200 + (buttonsCount * 400);

        buttonsCount++;
    }
}

function missing (event : Event) : void
{
    //trace("broken");
}
```

It successfully gets the JSON from the URL, but when it goes to add a symbol for each entry in the array, it simply does nothing.

This problem is only worsened by the fact that I'm using Flash 11 export in CS5, and therefore I can't use the built in Test Movie or trace to the console.

If anybody could point out what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in that `ListItem`? You have to assign your `listItem` some values from `data`, otherwise they are just blank.

Comment: Also, you can still use Flash debugger player (standalone app) to run your exported SWF in that and get access to console and error stack traces, should you have any. If you use this, you can `throw new Error("text")` if anything goes wrong and see what error is thrown. Also, as an alternate solution, you can use a text field with scrolling enabled as a logger, then just display it when necessary and review whatever text you've added in there. Use `addText()` for such purpose.